# I have created a generic database class to call database (SQL Server) from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am new to .net. Please help me what the things should I add here? How to add stored procedure? My aim is to keep `DataAccess` class in one project and use it in other project as .dll. In other project I just want to call dbclass and to add parameter, execute method only. Please help me

My code:

```
public class DataAccess
{
    string commandString;
    string commandType;
    private static string ConnectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["studentConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    public String commandStrings
    {
        get { return commandString; }
        set { commandString = value; }
    }

    public String commandTypes
    { 
        get { return commandType; }
        set { commandType = value; }
    }

    public void addparameters(String name, Object value)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
    }

    public DataTable Exec(String Query) 
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
        }

        try
        {               
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, connection);
            adapter.Fill(datatable);
            return datatable;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
        finally
        { 
             connection.Close();
        }

        return null;
    } 

    public int Execute(String Query)
    {
        int AffectedRows = 0;
        command.CommandText = Query;
        command.Connection = connection;

        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {   
            connection.Close();
            connection.Open();
        }

        try
        {              
            AffectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return AffectedRows;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
        finally
        {   
            connection.Close();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures are executed through SqlCommand, there's not much difference to running a insert/update statement.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_name", con); 

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;        
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParameter", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = someValue;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You should consider implementing `IDisposable` for the `DataAccess` class to dispose of db resources when they are not needed.

Comment: This one I expected